# Spring Tool Suite(STS) plugin for eclipse oxygen

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-oxygen

Not able to install standalone sts software or sts plugin for eclipse in my office system due to proxy issues. Can anyone provide the link for downloading zip of sts plugin which i can copy to my eclipse installation folder.

**Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)**

Comment: You can download from here. https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all

Comment: ...and [STS 4 can be downloaded from here](https://spring.io/tools). By the way, Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) is pretty old. You might require and want the current Eclipse version: 2019-09 (4.13).

Answer (score 1):

STS(Spring tool suite) is not available for eclipse oxygen in eclipse Marketplace, but one can install this in offline way(installed and working fine for version 4.7.3), steps are shared below:

1. Download springsource-tool-suite-X.X.XX.RELEASE-**.**.__-updatesite.zip file from https://spring.io/tools3/sts/all
2. Unzip this file
3. In eclipse goto Help->Install New Software -> Add -> Local -> browse unzipped folder
4. Select and Install and Restart eclipse to start using.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old topic but I had the same problem and here is the solution I found if Eclipse market place doesn't open/show anything because of the proxy:

The Eclipse Marketplace Client, some editions have a bug where it fails to open in certain cases. If nothing happens when you try to access the Eclipse Marketplace via “Help > Eclipse Marketplace”, please update the Marketplace Client plug-in by doing the following:

[image]

1. Go to Help > Install New Software
2. Paste the Marketplace Client update site url into the “Work with” field: http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/photon
3. Select the “EPP Marketplace Client” checkbox
4. Follow the wizard and restart your Eclipse to finish the installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a compatibility issue, another way is to upgrade to the latest eclipse version.

Answer (score 0):

i have been stuck here .finding links for sts to install explicitly.
finally this [link](https://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.7) helped me here

go to > install new softwares and then paste this link.